# Hermitian Matrices and skew-Hermitian Matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Should the diagonal in the Hermitian matrices always be all real or all imaginary? Or could the diagonal be either one?

Similarly, in the Skew-Hermitian, should the diagonal always be all Real or all imaginary? Or should the diagonal be all 0 or all 0 in the real component of the complex?

Thank you

Comment: Since a Hermaitian matrix are equal to their own conjugate transpose the diagonal elements must be their own conjugates. Since a skew-Hermitian matrix is the negative of it's conjugate transpose, the diagonal elements must be the negative of their conjugates. This is enough to answer the question.

Comment: Thank you. It helps to grasp easily.

Answer (score 0):

If $H$ is a hermitian matrix, then

$H^\dagger = H, \tag 1$

and by definiton

$H^\dagger = (H^T)^\ast; \tag 2$

thus,

$(H^T)^\ast = H, \tag 3$

or

$H^T = H^\ast; \tag 4$

now if $h_{ii}$ is a diagonal entry of $H$, it is fixed in place under

$H \mapsto H^T, \tag 5$

and is hence a diagonal  entry of $H^T$; but then in accord with (4) we have

$h_{ii} = h_{ii}^\ast, \tag 6$

implying

$h_{ii} \in \Bbb R. \tag 7$

Likewise, if $H$ is skew-hermitian, then (1) is replaced by

$H^\dagger = -H, \tag 8$

so (3)-(4) become

$(H^T)^\ast = -H, \tag 9$

$H^T = -H^\ast; \tag{10}$

diagonal entries of $H$ are still fixed under $H \mapsto H^T$, whence

$h_{ii} = -h_{ii}^\ast, \tag{11}$

that is,

$h_{ii} \in i\Bbb R, \tag{12}$

i.e., $h_{ii}$ is purely imaginary.